# Obtain the logcat filters from current run of my app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-logcat

I'm trying to extract logs of my app(currently running logs). From  MainActivity(currently) started till it exists. However when I try to use certain filters it dumps the previous old logs too. I searched stackoverflow, No big deal I didn't get an idea.
What I tried was

```
logcat -d -v time myapp:v dalvikvm:v System.err:v *:s
```

My Actual Code is

```
String cmd = "logcat -d -v time myapp:v dalvikvm:v System.err:v *:s";

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            reader = new InputStreamReader (process.getInputStream());
```

Please Help me out.